# Kentico 10 ObjectQuery join multiple tables

Tags: kentico

I am basically trying to run a query that gives me all the Users that have purchased a product with a particular SKU. Essentially this SQL here:

```
SELECT u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.Email
FROM COM_OrderItem oi INNER JOIN COM_Order o ON oi.OrderItemOrderID = o.OrderID
    INNER JOIN COM_Customer c ON o.OrderCustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN CMS_User u ON c.CustomerUserID = u.UserID
WHERE oi.OrderItemSKUID = 1013
```

I was trying to use the ObjectQuery API to try and achieve this but have no idea how to do this. The documentation [here](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/retrieving-database-data-using-objectquery-api) does not cover the specific type of scenario I am looking for. I came up with this just to try and see if it works but I don't get the three columns I am after in the result:

```
var test = OrderItemInfoProvider
                    .GetOrderItems()
                    .Source(orderItems => orderItems.Join<OrderInfo>("OrderItemOrderID", "OrderID"))
                    .Source(orders => orders.Join<CustomerInfo>("OrderCustomerID", "CustomerID"))
                    .Source(customers => customers.Join<UserInfo>("CustomerUserID", "UserID"))
                    .WhereEquals("OrderItemSKUID", 1013).Columns("FirstName", "LastName", "Email").Result;
```

I know this is definitely wrong and I would like to know the right way to achieve this. Perhaps using ObjectQuery is not the right approach here or maybe I can somehow just use raw SQL. I simply don't know enough about Kentico to understand the best approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the ObjectQuery you created is correct. I tested it and it is providing the correct results. Are you sure that there are indeed orders in the system, which contain a product with SKUID 1013 (you can check that in the COM_OrderItem database table)?

Also, how are you accessing the results? Iterating through the results should look like this:

```
    foreach (DataRow row in test.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        string firstName = ValidationHelper.GetString(row["FirstName"], "");
        string lastName = ValidationHelper.GetString(row["LastName"], "");
        string email = ValidationHelper.GetString(row["Email"], "");
    }
```

Comment: You are right. I was not accessing the results correctly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.